# Как установить русский язык в ESLint? для React+TypeSript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Как установить русский язык в ESLint? установила ESLint, прошла по инструкции его. можно ли сделать, чтобы он писал ошибки на русском языке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нашел по этой теме открытую задачу в проекте: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9870

Comment: Попробуйте в настройки добавить `"typescript.locale": "ru"`, не уверен, что это сработает на `eslint`.